# First day of next month with java Joda-Time

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

How would you rewrite the method below, which returns the first day of next month, with the `org.joda.time` package in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

```
public static Date firstDayOfNextMonth() {
    Calendar nowCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = nowCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = nowCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date dueDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    return dueDate;
}
```

Comment: Be carefule with the `nowCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1` if the current month is December.

Comment: why don't you accept an answer?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
   LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
   LocalDate d1 = today.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
```

A little easier and cleaner, isn't it? :-)

Update: If you want to return a date:

```
return new Date(d1.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis());
```

but I strongly advise you to avoid mixing pure DATE types (i.e. a day in the calendar, without time information) with DATETIME types, specially with a "physical" datetime type as is the hideous `java.util.Date` . It's somewhat like converting from-to integer and floating types, you must be careful.

Comment: Yeah, `LocalDate` objects are a slight bit harder to convert back to Java `Date` objects... and since LocalDate represents a whole day in Joda Time, I don't remember what the time component would be on conversion to a Date.

Comment: For those going the `LocalDate` route, it looks like using LocalDate.toDateMidnight().toDate() is the easiest way to convert it to a Java `Date` object with the time set to midnight.

Comment: `toDateMidnight()`  is not recommended http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665921/recommended-use-for-joda-times-datemidnight

Comment: All the "midnight" related classes and methods in Joda-Time are deprecated and should be avoided. Instead call the various "toDateTime" methods to produce a `DateTime` from a `LocalDate`. For example, [`toDateTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) where you pass the desired time zone. Dates do not always start at the time `00:00:00.0`, so Joda-Time will determine the first moment of the day appropriate for the specified time zone.

Answer (score 21):

I'm assuming you want to return a Date object, so:

```
public static Date firstDayOfNextMonth() {
    MutableDateTime mdt = new MutableDateTime();
    mdt.addMonths(1);
    mdt.setDayOfMonth(1);
    mdt.setMillisOfDay(0); // if you want to make sure you're at midnight
    return mdt.toDate();
}
```

Comment: This code is somewhat outmoded now (2014). (A) The designers of Joda-Time recommend against using the mutable classes. Instead, you can call many of the methods that return a new fresh immutable [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance. (B) The midnight-related methods are no longer recommended. Instead, call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) to get first moment of new day. Don't set millis to zero for midnight, as DST may mean there is no such midnight time.

Answer (score 16):

## Joda-Time

Here's my take on this problem, using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

### Immutable

Generally you should use the [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) versions of the Joda-Time classes. Nearly all the methods return a new instance of a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) rather than modify existing instance. Simplifies things, and makes for automatic thread-safety.

### Start-Of-Day

Use the newer method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) rather than setting time of day to zero. Because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies, on some days in some time zones, there is no midnight or 00:00:00 time of day.

### Convert: j.u.Date ↔ DateTime

To translate a Joda-Time `DateTime` instance to a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance, simply call [`toDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate()) method. No need for constructor on Date.

Going the other way, if you hava a java.util.Date and want a Joda-Time DateTime, simply pass the Date to the constructor of DateTime along with the desired [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object.

### Example Code

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
// Usually better to specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone ); // Or, for default time zone: new DateTime()
DateTime monthFromNow = now.plusMonths(1);
DateTime firstOfNextMonth = monthFromNow.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
DateTime firstMomentOfFirstOfNextMonth = firstOfNextMonth.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Or, if you are a maniac, string that all together in a single line of code.

```java
DateTime allInOneLine = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).plusMonths( 1 ).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Translate to an old java.util.Date for interaction with other classes/libraries.

```java
java.util.Date date = firstMomentOfFirstOfNextMonth.toDate();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "monthFromNow: " + monthFromNow );
System.out.println( "firstOfNextMonth: " + firstOfNextMonth );
System.out.println( "firstMomentOfFirstOfNextMonth: " + firstMomentOfFirstOfNextMonth );
System.out.println( "allInOneLine: " + allInOneLine );
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-21T02:46:16.834+01:00
monthFromNow: 2014-02-21T02:46:16.834+01:00
firstOfNextMonth: 2014-02-01T02:46:16.834+01:00
firstMomentOfFirstOfNextMonth: 2014-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
allInOneLine: 2014-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
date: Fri Jan 31 15:00:00 PST 2014
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. Inspired by Joda-Time, and intended to be its successor.

These new classes include the `TemporalAdjuster` interface ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/adjusters.html)) with a bunch of implementations in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (notice the plural `s`). Happens to have just the adjuster we need: [`firstDayOfNextMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfNextMonth--).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = today.with ( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth () );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "today: " + today + "  |  firstOfNextMonth: " + firstOfNextMonth );
```

> today: 2015-12-22  |  firstOfNextMonth: 2016-01-01

If you want a date-time rather than date-only, adjust.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = firstOfNextMonth.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

If you need to use the old java.util.Date for operating with old classes not yet updated to java.time, convert from an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) extracted from the ZonedDateTime object. An Instant is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

there is a method for that in Joda API:

```
Date date = new LocalDate().plusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().toDate();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The withMinimumValue() returns returns a LocalDate type. Add a toDate() call to the chain.

Comment: Thanks @AlexFedulov! I forgot that and already adjusted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

the same as before but converted also to java.util.Date

Date firstDayOfNextMonth = (new LocalDate().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1)).toDate();

Answer (score 1):

localDate = new LocalDate().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if 'I' get the question right, but here's my try :D..
like just don't add the +1 month???

```
public static Date firstDayOfNextMonth() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        int year = now.getYear();
        int month = now.getMonthValue();
        int day = now.getDayOfMonth();  

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        Date dueDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    return dueDate;
}
```

Comment: The question is about Joda-time which is a new implementation of the date/time classes.