# How to get name of the first day of a month?

Tags: java

How would I go about getting the first day of the month?  So for January, of this year, it would return Sunday.  And then for February it would return Wednesday.

Comment: create the date and then retrieve the day from it (format)

Comment: Search, my good man. [This SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786169/first-day-of-next-month-with-java-joda-time) does it both the crappy way, and the Joda Time way. Coincidentally also asked today. Tons of hits.

Comment: @RanRag It's over there on the right under the big "Related" header.

Comment: oh yes sorry, i don't know why i wrote that comment. I think I have done too much coding for the day.

Comment: It helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14241940/4813777

Answer (score 45):

To get the first date of the current month, use `java.util.Calendar`. First get an instance of it and set the field `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` to the first date of the month.  Since the first day of any month is 1, inplace of `cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`, 1 can be used here.

```
private Date getFirstDateOfCurrentMonth() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll want `cal.getActualMinimum` instead if the calendar object has been set to a specific month in the past.

Answer (score 16):

You can create a `Calendar` with whatever date you want and then do `set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` to get the first day of a month.

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 25);
     cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
     cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

     cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
     Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();  

     DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");   
     System.out.println("First Day of Month: " + sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public int getFirstDay(){
    Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

From there you can see if the int is equal to Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the Java 8 you can use the **TemporalAdjusters:**

This is an example:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

/**
 * Dates in Java8
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("Day of Month: " + localDate.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Month: " + localDate.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Year: " + localDate.getYear());

        System.out.printf("first day of Month: %s%n",
                localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()));
        System.out.printf("first Monday of Month: %s%n", localDate
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)));
        System.out.printf("last day of Month: %s%n",
                localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
        System.out.printf("first day of next Month: %s%n",
                localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth()));
        System.out.printf("first day of next Year: %s%n",
                localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextYear()));
        System.out.printf("first day of Year: %s%n",
                localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear()));

        LocalDate tomorrow = localDate.plusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Day of Month: " + tomorrow.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Month: " + tomorrow.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Year: " + tomorrow.getYear());
    }

}
```

The results would be:

```
Day of Month: 16
Month: MAY
Year: 2014
first day of Month: 2014-05-01
first Monday of Month: 2014-05-05
last day of Month: 2014-05-31
first day of next Month: 2014-06-01
first day of next Year: 2015-01-01
first day of Year: 2014-01-01
Last in Month Tuesday: 2014-05-27
Day of Month: 17
Month: MAY
Year: 2014
```

Comment: Informative, but you did not quite wrap it up -- Question asks for name of day.

Answer (score 3):

## `TemporalAdjuster`

In java 8 you can use the new [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) API.

To achieve the coveted result, give a try to the following. It prints the name of the given day.

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate l = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(l.getDayOfWeek());
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `now` gives you the current date.
- by calling `with` you can pass a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) which are a key tool for modifying temporal objects.
- `getDayOfWeek` Gets the day-of-week field, which is an enum `DayOfWeek`.
  This includes textual names of the values.

`TemporalAdjuster` has a brother class, called [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) which contains static methods regarding the adjustments, like the one you are looking for, the `firstDayOfMonth`

Comment: TemporalAdjuster Call requires API level 26, Please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Create `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` object, set date value and use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class method to format it.

```
 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
 cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
 cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);

 SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
 System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

Since Java 8 we can also use [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class which allows us to create [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects with specified days (first, last). Then We can simply convert these dates to [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)) and read its [`name`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--) property.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2012, 1);

String firstDay = ym.atDay(1).getDayOfWeek().name();
String lastDay = ym.atEndOfMonth().getDayOfWeek().name();

System.out.println(firstDay);
System.out.println(lastDay);
```

result:

```
SUNDAY
TUESDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time, soft-coded

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31159201/642706) by Pshemo was good and clever, but is hard-coded to English. Let's take a stab at it allowing for localization.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); // Time zone is crucial to determining a date.
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.now( zoneId );
LocalDate firstOfMonth = yearMonth.atDay( 1 );
```

### Formatter

Generate a textual representation of that [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). We specify a desired [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), in this case [`CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH). If omitted, your JVM’s current default Locale is implicitly applied; better to specify explicit Locale.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE" ).withZone( zoneId ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Exactly four 'E' letters means full form. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html#FULL
String output = formatter.format( firstOfMonth );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run.

> samedi

### `DayOfWeek` Enum

Another route is to use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. This enum includes a [`getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method where you specify both the [text style](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) (full name versus abbreviation) and a `Locale`.

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek() ;
String output = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE  , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and tricky answer**

```
    val calendar = Date()    
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00", Locale.getDefault())
    var result = sdf.format(calendar)
```

yyyy-MM-01 -> dd change to 01