# Get first date of current month in java

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to get to and from date where `ToDate` will have previous date and `FromDate` will have first date of the current month. For January it would be `1/1/2013` and so on. How to get the first date of the current month correctly? I am not able to do it.

```
today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
java.util.Date previousDay=today.getTime();
ToDate = sdfFile1.format(newjava.sql.Date(previousDay.getTime()));
today.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
java.util.Date nextDay=today.getTime();
FromDate = sdfFile1.format(new java.sql.Date(nextDay.getTime()));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first day of the current week and month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month)

Comment: The terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

try

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   // this takes current date
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());       // this returns java.util.Date
```

Updated ([Since Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
LocalDate todaydate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("Months first date in yyyy-mm-dd: " +todaydate.withDayOfMonth(1));
```

Comment: Be aware that the`HOUR_OF_DAY`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND` and `MILLISECOND` will have the values they have at the moment you create the `Calendar` or `Date` instance. You may want to set those values to 0, e.g. `c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)`.

Comment: See also this answer, that doesn't have the time problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37710768/1121497

Answer (score 38):

## tl;dr

> How to get the first date of the current month correctly?

```
LocalDate.now()
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() )
```

Or…

```
LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth( 1 )
```

Or…

```
YearMonth.now().atDay( 1 )
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The old classes have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

The java.time framework is inspired by the highly-successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, and explained in the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without time-of-day, use the `LocalDate` class. While `LocalDate` has no assigned time zone, we must specify a time zone in order to determine a date such as “today”. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal.

Time zone is crucial in determining today's date. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. Omitting the time zone means the JVM’s current time zone is automatically applied in determining the current date. Any code in the JVM can change the default at runtime, so you are walking on shifting sands. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly than rely implicitly on the current default.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

In code, first we determine today’s date as seen in the particular time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
```

Then we adjust the day-of-month to the 1st.

```
LocalDate firstOfCurrentMonth = today.with ( ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1 );
```

Or, more simply:

```
LocalDate firstOfCurrentMonth = today.withDayOfMonth( 1 ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "For zoneId: " + zoneId + " today is: " + today + " and first of this month is " + firstOfCurrentMonth );
```

> For zoneId: America/Montreal today is: 2015-11-08 and first of this month is 2015-11-01

Alternatively, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). For your purpose, you will find handy implementations in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note plural `s`), specifically [`firstDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfMonth--).

```
LocalDate firstOfCurrentMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you need a time of day, remember that `00:00:00.000` is *not* always the first moment of the day because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies. So let java.time determine the correct time of the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = firstOfCurrentMonth.atStartOfDay ( zoneId );
```

> 2015-11-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't mention using `TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()`.

Comment: @DeanSchulze The `TemporalAdjuster` approach works well too. If you want the *end* of the month, then certainly go the [`TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfMonth--) as we would not easily specify a certain day-of-month number with the `ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH` approach.

Comment: I am getting `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth` when calling `Instant.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())`

Comment: @tak3shi Use `ZonedDateTime` rather than `Instant` for that.

Comment: @BasilBourque You already have three examples of how to get the first date of the current month correctly, but it could also be done with `LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1)`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I added your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Joda Time**

If I am understanding the question correctly, it can be done very easily by using joda time

```
LocalDate fromDate = new LocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate toDate = new LocalDate().minusDays(1);
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer because it sets the time to 0. It goes from first day of month (at 0:00h) to the previous day (at 0:00h). Sometimes you may want to set `toDate = new LocalDate()` so it goes until last midnight (0:00h of today).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`withDayOfMonth(int dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfMonth-int-) method from **java8** to return first day of month:

```
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
System.out.println(firstDay);   // 2019-09-01
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a Date (that can be used in JPA later on), I did

```
Date startOfMonth = Date.from(LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

- I take current date LocalDate.now()
- Move it to first day of the month withDayOfMonth(1)
- Move it to the sart of the day atStartOfDay() to get rid of hours and minutes
- and deal with the TimeZone issues by changing it into an Instant with the "right" ZoneOffset.

Comment: I recommend you stop using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want the time is set to 0 the code is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateCalculations {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Date firstDateOfCurrentMonth = aCalendar.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zZ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String dayFirst = sdf.format(firstDateOfCurrentMonth);
    System.out.println(dayFirst);
  }
}
```

You can check online easily without compiling by using: 
http://www.browxy.com/

Answer (score 1):

### Works Like a charm!

```
public static String  getCurrentMonthFirstDate(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    //System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime())); 
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

//Correction :output =02-01-2018[image]

Comment: 02-07-2018 is hardly the first day of the current month? The `SimpleDateFormat` class you are using is not only long outmoded (like `Calendar`), but also notoriously troublesome. Please don’t teach the young ones to use it. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As noted by Ole V.V., the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Some of us are still using legacy, you know :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); //2020-01-12
date.withDayOfMonth(1); //2020-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

First day of month of a date:

```
public static Date firstDayOfMonth(Date d) {
    
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(d);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    
    return calendar.getTime();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using JodaTime package
depends on ur requirement can use Zone it or you can remove

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
DateTime previousMonthStartDate = DateTime.now().minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Calcutta"));
    String previousMonthStDate = previousMonthStartDate.toString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
    System.out.println(previousMonthStDate);
```