# Set Calendar to first week of a month in Java

Tags: java, android, calendar

i'm trying to set Calendar object -> today to a particular day of first week of a month.

```
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
    today.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    today.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    today.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    today.getTime();

    today.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    today.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    today.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,today.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, getDay()+1);

    Log.d(TAG, "Test : "+getName()+", time : "+ today.getTime()+"  ,year : "+year+"   ,month : "+ month);
```

problem is, the calendar is returning the date of day set of current week.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code:

```
public static String getEightWeeksDateString() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

This return Date in string format, then you should convert it into what u want

Comment: the above method returns string of first date of month, but i want to set `today ` to one particular day of first week.

Comment: just change return statement and convert into date directoly

Comment: sorry, i dnt get you. i would appreciate if you explain by code.

Comment: public static Date getEightWeeksDateString() throws ParseException {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
  String str=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00").parse(str);
 }

Comment: try this and modify date pattern if u want

Answer (score 0):

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   // this takes current date
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: i put the line, but still it returned the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241836/get-first-date-of-current-month-in-java

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   // this takes current date
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());   // this returns java.util.Date

Comment: i want to set the day of week to `day`, and week to first week of month.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DAY_OF_MONTH field in class calendar, which you are required to change if you want to accomplish your goal. Look in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). You just need to use set method :

```
today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: still it returns the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. It will return the date as same day as of today but for first week of month.

```
public String getDayFromFirstWeek() {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault());

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+ Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1) % 7);
    return formatter.format(date.getTime());
}
```