# How to read the files from Azure Blob Storage with folder structure as 'StartDateOfMonth-EndDatefMonth'?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Scenario

We have azure blob storage container with following folder structure. 
•   20190601-20190630

Basically, this folder will contain daily CSV files for the given month.

This folder structure is dynamic. So, in the next month, folder 20190701-20190731 will be populated with daily CSV files.

Problem

On daily basis, need to move these files from azure blob storage to azure data lake using azure data factory (v2).

How to specify folder structure (dynamically) in the Input Dataset (Azure Blob Storage) in Azure Data Factory(V2)?

Example: 
20190601-20190630/*.CSV    for the month June 2019

Basically, StartDateOfMonth and EndDateOfMonth are dynamic.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your dataset folder path like:

```
   "folderPath": {
                        "value": "@concat( 
                               formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.scheduledRunTimeStart, 'yyyyMMdd'), 
                               '-',
                               formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.scheduledRunTimeEnd, 'yyyyMMdd')
                               , '/'
                        "type": "Expression"
    }
```

And pass the parameters into dataset:

```
"parameters": {
    "scheduledRunTimeStart": {
        "type": "String"
    },
    "scheduledRunTimeEnd": {
        "type": "String"
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing the date time parameter is correct but we need to pass the **StartDateOfMonth** and **EndDateOfMonth**. The parent folder structure will be as follows                                                                                                                                                       For June month - 20190601-2019063                                                                                 For July  month  - 20190701-20190731                                                                               For August month - 20190801-20190830

Comment: @MangeshT. You could format the date string first follow your rules ,then pass them into pipeline as parameters. Fox example,use java Calendar jar sdk:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241836/get-first-date-of-current-month-in-java