# Retrieve the first day of the week of a given month

Tags: java, calendar

Given this code it will print out the correct month and year but seems to display random days that are usually incorrect.  I have looked over some links including [here](http://www.java-examples.com/display-day-week-using-java-calendar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997228/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-a-month)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DayOfTheWeek {
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  int month;
  int year;
  String[] monthString;
  public String monthOfInspection() {
    String Month = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select month of inspection: ");
    month = Integer.parseInt(Month);
    monthString = new String[] {
      "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };
    return monthString[month - 1];
  }
  public int yearOfInspection() {
    if(month == 1) {
      now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      now.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    }
    year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return year;
  }
  public void dayOfTheWeek() {
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    now.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 0);
    String[] strDays = new String[] {
      "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    };
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, year);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, monthString[month - 1]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strDays[now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) - 1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the order of settings, set day of month after the month, and don't set day of week in month.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` instead of `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`.

```
public void dayOfTheWeek() {
    now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    now.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    String[] strDays = new String[] {
      "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    };
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, year);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, monthString[month - 1]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strDays[now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) -     1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correct `month` and `year` this is what you can do:

```
now.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
now.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```