# Getting day of the week

Tags: android

With this code, I get the days that make up a given month, but if I want to get if the month starts on a Monday or Tuesday, as I do?

```
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(anni, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);
int giorni = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 28
```

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997228/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-a-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
int anni = 2014;
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(anni, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);

int dayOfWeek = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch (dayOfWeek) {
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        break;
}
```

Or you can replace each case with values between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday) since `dayOfWeek` is an `int` between 1 and 7.

### UPDATE

To get the full name of the day:

```
String day = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays()[dayOfWeek];
```

Comment: I did this test, but in the log, I reported that the week has 7 days and the days of the week

Comment: you misunderstood the result, it gives you 7 because 1 Feb 2014 is Saturday and `Calendar.SATURDAY == 7`

Comment: you asked **"I want to get if the month starts on a Monday or Tuesday"**... So your test is saying that month starts with a Saturday

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, but if you want to have the day in text format as I do? 
I would take days to display adaper