# Java Calendar - get Hour and Minute

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get Date from DB and get from date year, month, day, hour and minutes

The way i'm doing it is:

```
Date dateStart = calendarEvents.getDateStart();

        java.util.Calendar calendarEventStart = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarEventStart.setTime(dateStart);

        java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

        parseDateToCalendar.setYearStart(now.get(calendarEventStart.YEAR));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(now.get(calendarEventStart.MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setDayStart(now.get(calendarEventStart.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setHourStart(now.get(calendarEventStart.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(now.get(calendarEventStart.MINUTE));
```

And java suprise me, cose in DB my date is:

```
2014-05-21 04:15:00.0
```

dateStart variable has also date

```
2014-05-21 04:15:00.0
```

but `now.get(calendarEventStart.HOUR_OF_DAY` display: `14`

and `now.get(calendarEventStart.MINUTE)` display: `46`

WHY and what to do to get correct hour and minutes ?

YOU WERE RIGHT - NOW IS CORRECT DATE, BUT NOW I HAVE ANOTHE ISSUE:

```
        java.util.Calendar calendarEventStart = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendarEventStart.setTime(dateStart);

        parseDateToCalendar.setYearStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.YEAR));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setDayStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setHourStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.MINUTE));
```

Display:

```
parseDateToCalendar.getYearStart() = 2014 - THIS IS OK (YEAR)
parseDateToCalendar.getMonthStart() = 30 - !!WRONG - THIS SHOULD BE MINUTE
parseDateToCalendar.getDayStart() = 21 - THIS IS OK (DAY)
parseDateToCalendar.getHourStart() = 4 - !!WRONG - THIS SHOULD BE MONTH
parseDateToCalendar.getMinuteStart() = 0 - !!WRONG - HERE SHOULD BE VALUE FROM MONTH
```

Comment: This is Java code and not DB/database, please can you tell us what sort of database your using? if you using mysql you can choose SELECT NOW(); now for Java you can use the LocalDate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997228/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-a-month/23699152#23699152

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the info from the now date and not from the one you retrieved.
            Date dateStart = calendarEvents.getDateStart();

```
        java.util.Calendar calendarEventStart = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarEventStart.setTime(dateStart);

        parseDateToCalendar.setYearStart(calendarEventStart .get(calendarEventStart.YEAR));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart .get(calendarEventStart.MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setDayStart(calendarEventStart .get(calendarEventStart.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        parseDateToCalendar.setHourStart(calendarEventStart .get(calendarEventStart.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart .get(calendarEventStart.MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 1):

now is the actual date! Not the date from DB