# Java: round unix time (Long) to first day of the month

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to round a unix time to the first day of the month in Java, but without success. Example:

> 1314057600 (Tue, 23 Aug 2011 00:00:00 GMT)

to

> 1312156800 (Mon, 01 Aug 2011 00:00:00 GMT)

The unix time I'm reading from a file and storing it as a Long inside a variable (variable named "valor"). 
So far I've been able to create a Java timestamp with it

```
LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(valor), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

and create a new timestamp for the beggining of the month:

```
LocalDate key = LocalDate.of(timestamp.getYear(), timestamp.getMonthValue(), 1);
```

How do I get this new timestamp as a Long?

Comment: First thing to think about: which time zone are you interested in? Always UTC? And I assume the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: Try [this] from an earlier post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21247526/442256)

Comment: Time zone is not important in this case, and yes Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @sfk note that the answer you link is about Joda time, whereas OP is asking about the Java 8 time API.

Comment: Scrolling down @sfk link, there is some info on Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this sounds like it would work:

```
key.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()
```

(Assuming you want it in the system's default timezone).

Comment: Perfect! My mistake is that I used LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime. LocalDate doesn't have `toEpochSecond`, only `toEpochDay`, which is not the same.